# How to read JSON url for android development?

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to android development and I am trying to create an android application for currency conversion. I need to read JSON URL to get the rate. I get user input for AMOUNT, CURRENCYFROM and CURRENCYTO. The url I'm trying to read is the following: http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1

Once url read I want to assign the values to variables. Specifically I'm trying to get the rate and multiply by user input for AMOUNT.

I want to get the Dictionaries(I think the JSON file has dictionaries) value and keys and convert it to data types variables such as int or string. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are lots and lots of tutorials on fetching and parsing JSON feed, have you tried search before asking your question?

Comment: I did do research but have not found anything useful and understandable on any websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
public API_Rate_Model getRate() {
API_Rate_Model result = new API_Rate_Model();
 try {
                HttpResponse response;
                HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1");
                try {
                    response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                    String JSONString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),
                            "UTF-8");
                    Log.i(BaseID.TAG, JSONString);

                JSONObject json = null;
                json = new JSONObject(JSONString);
                            result.setTo(json.getString("to"));
                            result.setRate(json.getDouble("rate"));
                            result.setFrom(json.getString("from"));
                            result.setValue(json.getDouble("v"));

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return result;
}
```

API_Rate_Model Class :

```
public class API_Rate_Model {

    private String to;
    private Double rate;
    private String from;
    private Double value;

    public API_001_Model() {
        to = "";
        rate = 0.0;
        from = "";
        value = 0.0;
    }

    public Double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(Double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }       

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }  

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to= to;
    }  
}
```

this code will sent a post to the server then convert the response to string then process the JSON String response. I hope my answer can helps you, but if you have any question feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: how can i get rate out of the try and catch?

Comment: 1st option simply create the variable outside the try catch, 2nd option create a class model then create an object from that model, then insert the value to the object and insert my code to a function that return that model, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I get the first option but when I set the variables outside they change inside the try catch but after the try catch when i use those variable they are not the same as inside the try catch. initally i set rate to 0, then inside try catch i set it  equal to the rate from JSOn file, and outside the try catch i multiply rate with AMOUNT, i get 0, you get wat im saying.

Comment: @user2698566 please see my updated answer :) I hope you can understand it, I give you my 2nd option because I think you can use this function in many condition, and you can modify it yourself for the future use